# elasticsearch mutiple word synonms not working

Tags: elasticsearch, synonym

I am new to elasticsearch and i am trying to configure synonyms but it is not working as expected.

I have following data in my fields
1) Techincal Lead, Module Lead, Software Engineer, Senior Software Engineer

I want if I search for tl then it should retun "Technical Lead" or "tl"
However it is returning me "Technical Lead" and "Module Lead" because lead is tokenized at index tme.

Could you please help me in getting resolve this issue with exact settings.

I have seen that index time and search time tokenization but unable to understand that.

synonyms.txt:

> tl,TL => Technical Lead
>
> se,SE => Software Engineer
>
> sse => Senior Software Engineer

Mapping file:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "synonym"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "tweet": {
      "properties": {
        "Domain": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "synonym"
        },
        "Designation": {
          "analyzer": "synonym",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "City": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "synonym"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tokens are identical here, so you have that part down. What you need to do is ensure that you are doing an "AND" match instead of an "or" as it appears to be just matching on any word rather than all.

Check out your tokens:

```
localhost:9200/test/_analyze?analyzer=synonym&text=technical lead
localhost:9200/test/_analyze?analyzer=synonym&text=tl
```

And the query

```
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "domain": {
            "query": "tl",
            "operator": "and"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Usually you want your search and index analyzers to be the same. However, there are many advanced examples where this is not preferable. However, in the case with synonyms, often you do not want to use synonyms in one or the other when you have expansions turned on. 
     i.e. tl,technical lead

However, since you are using => type of synonyms, this really doesn't matter because all words will be converted into the word on the right rather than creating a bunch of tokens for every word between the commas.